# How to get a unique number everyday from every android device (i.e same number from every device) running on any version of android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, datetime, datetime-format

I want to get a unique number everyday that can be generated from any android device and every device should generate same number.
I tried getting the date but older version of android doesn't support locale time zone,
and then I used this code

```
        val df = DateFormat.getDateInstance()
        var dff = DateFormat.getTimeInstance()
        var localDate = df.format(Date())
        df.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("gmt")
        val gmtDate = df.format(Date())
        val localTime = dff.format(Date())
```

But this generated the date in different format from different devices , but I want same format from every version of android above 6.

Comment: Does that mean that you want every Android device to generate the same number no matter when it was generated in 24-hour window?

Comment: You don't want a local timezone, because then devices in different timezones would give different answers.  You must use (as answer below suggests) the UTC timestamp.

Comment: I know for Android O and higher that we can get the date in ISO format but what I need is for Android 6 and higher to generate the same format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code to get the date and time in same format from any device. This works on Android 6.0 and also on Android 11.

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        val df = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
        df.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("gmt")
        val dff =SimpleDateFormat("yy-MMM-dd, HH:mm:ss aa")
        val dfff =SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")
        val gmtDate = df.format(Date())
        val localDateTime = dff.format(Date())
        val isoDate=dfff.format(Date())
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```java
java.time.LocalDate
.now( ZoneOffset.UTC )
.atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC )
.toInstant()
.getEpochSecond()
```

## Details

Your question is unclear. Perhaps what you ask is how to determine the first moment of the day as seen in UTC for the current moment.

Use only *java.time* classes for date-time work. Never use the terribly flawed legacy classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`.

The *java.time* classes are built into Android 26+. For earlier Android, the latest tooling brings most of the functionality via “API de-sugaring”.

```
Instant startOfTodayUtc = 
    LocalDate
    .now( ZoneOffset.UTC )
    .atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC )
    .toInstant() ;
long secondsSinceEpochReference = startOfTodayUtc.getEpochSecond() ;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering ,this requires Android O and higher but I am targetting devices after Marshmallow, so this won't work in Android 6.0

Comment: @RaunitVerma Did you investigate “API desugaring” in the latest tooling, as I described? [*Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [*Java 8+ API desugaring support (Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0+)*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring). I see no limit to older versions stated there. Indeed, I see a mention of fixing bugs in Android 5.

Answer (score 0):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` gives you [a UTC timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()), how about that? You can divide it by `(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)` to round it to the nearest day (possibly some issues there with leap seconds but you may not care)

Answer (score 0):

i know your question, you want get a global unique in your every device, i have two methods:

1. you can build a center generator the unique number;
2. you can learn **Snowflake algorithm**， this method use time and ip
   to generate global unique number;

wish help yuo.